# Sort JS objects by value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following JavaScript object:

```
{
    date  : 'some date',
    name  : 'some name'
}
```

I have 10 of these objects, half will have one value for `name`  - tableA. And the other half will have a different value for `name` - tableB.

I want to break these objects down into different tables depending on the value of `name`, **I won't know the `name` value of my object.**

So for the 5 objects in the tableA table:

```
tableA
---------------
date  : 'some date'
date  : 'some date'
date  : 'some date'
date  : 'some date'
date  : 'some date'
```

And tableB

```
tableB
---------------
date  : 'some date'
date  : 'some date'
date  : 'some date'
date  : 'some date'
date  : 'some date'
```

I'll use jQuery to render all this. I'm assuming I'll need something like

```
  jQuery.each(objects, function(index, object) {
      //build my table
  }
```

I'm just not sure of the logic needed to accomplish what I want. Not the actual code to build my HTML, but the logic required to break my object into different 'groups'. I hope that makes sense.

Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var data = [{"date":"some date", "name":"tableA"},
            {"date":"some date", "name":"tableB"},
            {"date":"some date", "name":"tableA"},
            {"date":"some data", "name":"tableB"},
            {"date":"some data", "name":"tableC"},
            {"date":"some data", "name":"tableC"},
            {"date":"some data", "name":"Whatever"}];

var table = {};
$.each(data,function(index_data,obj_data){
    if(typeof table[obj_data.name] == 'undefined'){//there's the name in obj already?
        table[obj_data.name] = [{"date":obj_data.date,"name":obj_data.name}];//if no,then create an array and add the obj 
    }else{
        table[obj_data.name].push({"date":obj_data.date,"name":obj_data.name});//if yes add the obj to array
    }
});
```

here's the sample [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pjy31qz2/1/)

it will create the property of `table` object that is `name`'s property of  `data`object and add the array of objects that has name's property of `data` object is the same of name's property of `table` object

feel free to ask me if you don't understand :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use brilliant function of JavaScript - **filter**.

For example let's imagine you have array of objects:

```
var data = [{"date":"date1", "name":"tableA"},
            {"date":"date2", "name":"tableB"},
            {"date":"date3", "name":"tableA"},
            {"date":"date4", "name":"tableB"}];
```

You can describe two functions.
Like:

```
function all_A(el) {
    if(el.name == 'tableA') {
        return true;
    }
}

function all_B(el) {
    if(el.name == 'tableB') {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Function **all_A** will return true for each element if name attribute of it element is "TableA". Something similar for **all_B**.

Then you need just run **filter** function on your data array. 
Like that:

```
var table_A = data.filter(all_A);
var table_b = data.filter(all_B);
```

Here is working example :) - http://jsfiddle.net/32a97n1b/

Comment: Thanks a lot KryDos, but I won't actually know the name value of object. I didn't state that in my original question. I've updated my question now.

Comment: What do you mean? you have two arrays. You can go though these arrays in the $.each loop and take "date" attribute from each object in these arrays

Answer (score 0):

Try using following code. It will give you keys in json object.

```
for (data in objArray){
  console.log(data);
}
```

Further you can access individual element depending on your key and filter them

Answer (score 0):

So you want to group the data into separate lists by the "name" column:

```
function group(column){
    return function(p,c){
        if (!p[c[column]]){
            p[c[column]] = [];
        }
        p[c[column]].push(c);
        return p
    }
}

data.reduce(group("name"),{});
```